# XPath, return value of element whose ID matches link attribute and other attribute of second element?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am a beginner working with XPath and need to complete a task that returns the value of an XML element if another element has attribute type=X AND attribute link matching the ID of the first element.  The elements have different parents (these parents are siblings of each other).

Sample of the XML:

```
    <orders>
<order orderID="o1">
    <shipfrom>
        <company>
            <name>XYZ Company</name>
            <address>
                <addressline1>Building 1</addressline1>
                <addressline2>Floor 3</addressline2>
                <addressline3>Company Street</addressline3>
                <city>Cork</city>
                <country>Ireland</country>
                <postcode>XYZ123</postcode>
            </address>
        </company>
    </shipfrom>
    <shipto>
        <person>
            <firstname>Mary</firstname>
            <lastname>O'Brien</lastname>
            <emailaddress>maryobrien@email.ie</emailaddress>
        </person>
        <address>
            <addressline1>12 House Estate</addressline1>
            <addressline2>Estate Road</addressline2>
            <addressline3></addressline3>
            <city>Dublin</city>
            <country>Ireland</country>
            <postcode>D41234</postcode>
        </address>
    </shipto>
    <items>
        <item itemID="i1">
            <description>Blue Biro</description>
            <quantity>20</quantity>
            <price>0.10</price>
            <code>BIROBLU</code>
        </item>
        <item itemID="i2">
            <description>Black Biro</description>
            <quantity>20</quantity>
            <price>0.10</price>
            <code>BIROBLA</code>
        </item>
    </items>
    <payments>
        <payment type="cash">
            <amount>2.00</amount>
        </payment>
        <payment type="cash">
            <amount>2.00</amount>
        </payment>
    </payments>
    <history>
        <status link="i1" type="outofstock">
            <date>
                <day>08</day>
                <month>10</month>
                <year>2016</year>
            </date>
        </status>
        <status link="i2" type="dispatched">
            <date>
                <day>08</day>
                <month>10</month>
                <year>2016</year>
            </date>
        </status>
    </history>
</order>
```

The task is to list all item details that have a particular status.

Currently I have this:

```
//items[following-sibling::history/status[@type='dispatched']]/item
```

However, it is returning all items in an order, even if only one of them is of the status listed.

I assume that I need to create an additional condition - so if the attribute type is 'dispatched' and the link equals the itemID, return the details.

But I have no idea how to do this!  Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use item as context node rather than items, and then you can use link to restrict the result to the current itemID; this should work:

```
//item[../following-sibling::history/status[@type='dispatched']/@link=@itemID]
```

Comment: Good (+1), or since `item`-`history` order probably doesn't matter, and since  `/./` can reduce to `/`, you could use this slightly simpler XPath: `//item[../../history/status[@type='dispatched']/@link=@itemID]`

Comment: It's now working beautifully - thanks to both of you, I've learned something new and learned how to make it even simpler.